# conditional sum for csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have extracted a csv file in python as a list where each column has info like name, type, color and price of a car. I have to write a new CSV file with a column that calculates the total price of the cars in 'type B'

name                                type            color                 price
Honda                                 A              Black                 200
BMW                                   B              Blue                  100
lexus                                 B              Red                   200
nissan                                A              grey                  200
marcedez                              B              Blue                  300
Toyota                                A              white                 200

So i wrote my code as
total = 0
for col in reader:
for val in (col[3]):
for type in (col[1]):
if (type == 'B'):
total = total +val

But python gives me error like : total = toal +val
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Please share your full question, like the data in the form of array, and what is the condition and what is the answer you are looking for? I can see you have mentioned `total`, and not used `total` anywhere. No `somme` defined. Your question needs more clarification in the form of data, and more concrete details to the question

Comment: Also have a look in how you can format your code. Select it and hit Ctrl+k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatted code looks like this, I've added some comments:

```
total = 0
for col in reader:                  # csv.reader contains lines rather then columns
    for val in (col[3]):            # it is pointless looping over a single value
        for type in (col[1]):       # idem
            if (type == 'B'):
                total = total +val  # all cells are read as strings, so val is a string
```

Think in lines/rows rather than in columns and your code could look something like this:

```
total = 0
for line in reader:
    if line[1] == 'B':
        total = total + int(line[3])  # string values must be converted to int
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, one of the variable being used in a String(most likely the "val" being used.

Better convert it to integer and then perform an addition which shall solve the problem

Comment: I have corrected the error. But now instead of adding the values in the cells , it adds some random numbers  like 1,3, 6, 10 .